# Can a Soulknife make a whip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, psionics

What the title says. Can a soulknife get a 15 foot reach weapon that does (I guess?) 1d8 points of non-lethal damage and has disarm?

How would it work? Or is it undefined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A typical soulknife could form a mind blade that *looks* like a whip, but that mind blade wouldn't *function* like a whip…

By default the weapon that a [soulknife](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/) forms is generic, possessing only the statistics and qualities the supernatural ability [**form mind blade**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Form-Mind-Blade-Su-) and other soulknife class features describe the mind blade as possessing.

So a soulknife that uses only the supernatural ability **form mind blade** forms either a light, one-handed, or two-handed weapon that deals a size-based 1d6, 1d8, or 2d6 points of damage, that possesses a threat range of 19–20, and so on like the class describes. For example, a soulknife could decide that the mind blade she forms *looks* like a [halberd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/halberd/), [traveling kettle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/traveling-kettle-monk-group/), or [whip](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/whip/), but that mind blade still won't possess the picked weapon's qualities or statistics (e.g. it won't have the brace and trip qualities, it won't be a special monk weapon,  or it won't have the disarm, reach, and other qualities, respectively).

#### …But a soulknife can take a blade skill to form an actual mind blade whip

A soulknife that wants to form a mind blade that functions like a whip takes the [**emulate melee weapon**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/#Emulate_Melee_Weapon) (whip) blade skill:

> The soulknife can form her mind blade to replicate any single melee weapon, chosen at the time she takes this blade skill. The soulknife is proficient with her mind blade in this form and it functions in all ways as the chosen weapon. This blade skill may be taken multiple times; each time, it allows the soulknife to form her mind blade to replicate a different melee weapon. This blade skill may not be used with the mind bolt.

This blade skill allows the soulknife to form a mind blade that "functions in all ways as the chosen weapon," therefore for example, allowing a soulknife to use whip tricks with her new mind blade whip.

Keep in mind that benefits from the class feature [**enhance mind blade**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Enhanced-Mind-Blade) do apply to this mind blade whip, but this mind blade whip uses whip statistics whenever possible (e.g. effort needed to wield, damage, damage type, threat range, weapon qualities like nonlethal) instead of those spelled out by the form mind blade ability. For example, a typical soul knife that's wielding a mind blade whip that wants to deal lethal damage with it suffers a −4 penalty on the attack roll, and that mind blade whip's typical threat range is 20 instead of the generic mind blade's threat range of 19–20.

---

***Note:** A mind blade whip can be formed in at least one other way (see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/war-soul-soulknife-archetype#TOC-Discipline-Blade-Shapes-Su-)), but the emulate melee weapon (whip) blade skill is the most accessible way.*